# AngularJS not receiving broadcasts in controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a basic HTML game at the minute, and I have the following page (excluding normal HTML and Angular.js):

```
<div id="gameContainer" ng-controller="gameController">
    <div id="gameHead">
        <!-- Head bar -->
    </div>
</div>

<div id="debugContainer" ng-controller="debugController">
    <ul id="debugList">
        <li ng-repeat="log in logs">
            <span class="logTime">{{ log.time }}:</span> {{ log.message }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have three more JS files defined at the end of the HTML document:

**app.js:**

```
var game = angular.module('mystikApp', []);
```

**debugController.js:**

```
game.controller('debugController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope){
    // Log element
    $scope.logs = [];

    // Padding
    var padZeros = function(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }

    $scope.$on('helloWorld', function(e, args){
        alert(args.message);
    });

    // Add a new log entry
    $scope.addLogEntry = function(msg){
        var d = new Date();
        var hour = d.getHours();
        var min = d.getMinutes();
        var time = padZeros(hour) + ':' + padZeros(min);

        var newEntry = {
            message: msg,
            time: time
        };

        $scope.logs.push(newEntry);
    }

    $scope.$on('addLogEntry', function(e, args){
        $scope.addLogEntry(args.message);
        alert('Log entry added, msg: ' + args.message);
    });
}]);
```

**gameController.js:**

```
game.controller('gameController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('addLogEntry', {message: 'Welcome!'});

    $scope.$emit('helloWorld', {message: 'Hello World!'});
}]);
```

The JS files are loaded in the order they are listed above, and the second `helloWorld` 'emit' event is just an attempt to get this working.

### The issue

So when the game has loaded (the `gameController.js` file), I wanted to log a message like 'game loaded' to the log box. For some reason it seems the debug controller never receives the event, and I've looked at all the code samples I could find regarding the use of `$broadcast` and `$emit`, and I'm stumped as to why this isn't working now.

I have seen a few people recommending using services in place of this, but I'd rather stick with broadcasting for the minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed my whole original answer after reading your comment :)

The code that you have now works perfectly fine if you apply it to an `ng-click` event for example.

What I see that you want is when the page is loaded to `$broadcast` the event. The issue here, with your current code, is that the `$broadcasts` are not being caught because everything (whatever it may be) is not completely loaded yet.

AngularJS has embedded [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element): a tiny subset of jQuery features. It happens to implement the `ready()` event which fires when the DOM is completely loaded.

Here is my suggestion:

```
game.controller('gameController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope){
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('addLogEntry', {message: 'Welcome!'});
        $scope.$apply();
    });
}]);
```

You have to use `$scope.$apply()` otherwise when you do `$scope.addLogEntry` nothing will happen. This is because the `ready()` is a jqLite event not and AngularJS event. `$scope.$apply()` will force the digest cycle to run and update your scopes.

Comment: Apologies, this is previously what I had written in my code. I changed it to `$scope` out of desperation, looking for the issue. I've updated my code, and yes, `debugController` is supposed to receive events from the other controllers

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had read about `$apply()` before but didn't give it much thought in this scenario - I'll read up further on it

Answer (score 0):

here is your problem. 
When you create a controll width it a new $scope was created. 
That new $scope is a child of $rootScope.

Knowing that we can say that $broadcast sends events from top to bottom, and $emmit from bottom to top.

So, if you want to communicate controls in the same level you have to $broadcast from a parent level.

```
game.controller('gameController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('addLogEntry', {message: 'Welcome!'});
    ....
}]);
```

Comment: Oops! This is the same as what I just commented on the last answer: I previously had `$rootScope` in my code, but I changed it to see if I needed `$scope` instead - I just hadn't changed it back. Sorry!